# EazyBi & JIRA SLA report for only specific date created tickets

Tags: jira, jira-plugin

I need to get SLA report for tickets created after a specific date:

- For more clarification referring to this example  [- Met vs Breached](https://docs.eazybi.com/eazybi/learn-more/learn-eazybi-through-sample-reports/samples-jira-service-management/sla-met-vs-breached?_gl=1*uwtj1k*_ga*MTE5Nzg1MjYxMi4xNjcxNzE3NjU1*_ga_LKTNY5C56W*MTY4NTYyOTk0Mi4zMS4xLjE2ODU2MzQ2MjQuNTguMC4w)
- If you filtered by current year
- Then Drill though issues in January 2023
  You can find. [[IP-31]](https://eazybi-training.atlassian.net/browse/IP-31) - created in 31/12/2022 and involved in current year filter
  What i need to exclude all of tickets created before a date from this SLA report

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

In eazyBI, measures are tied to the *Time* dimension based on specific dates. In the case of SLA measures - their current or previous cycle dates.

To look at it from the perspective of the date the issue was created and consider whether the SLA is breached or met, use the measure "Issues created" combined with the dimension *<SLA> Breached*. In the provided examples case, *Time to first response Breached*.